# Проверить есть-ли пользователь в списке или нет Websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js

При подключении каждому пользователю присваиваю ID

```
ws.onclient=userId;
```

А как проверить пользователь он-лайн или нет?

```
 wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
                   if (client.onclient === userId) {
                       console.log('Онлаин')
                   }
               });
```

Например если он онлайн то данный код вернет что он онлаин. А как вернуть если он не онлайн?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим у вас есть массив всех пользователей

```
let users = ["1", "2", "3" ...]
```

Вы можете скопировать его в другой массив, скажем оффлайн пользователей и при проверке через

```
 let offline = users
 wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
    if (offline.includes(client.onclient)) {
       console.log('Онлаин');
       offline.splice(offline.indexOf(client.onclient), 1);
    }
 });
```

Таким образом в массиве `offline` остануться только те айди, которых нет в `wss.clients`